# PHP on centos 6 not working

Tags: centos, mysql, php, selinux, apache-httpd

I have installed PHP, MySQL, Apache on CentOS 6, now I have restarted the Apache and mysql, to test PHP I have created a `index.php` on `/var/www/html/test/` now once I go to `localhost/test/index.php` then it shows only PHP source code like this:
[image]

From Gnouc comment, I understand that it is due to SELinux security layer.
To work with HTML directory i did this in my terminal, but still i have the same result:

```
[root@localhost www]# chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t html
changing security context of `html`
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is `SELinux` enable?

Comment: if it is enable should i disable it? and if so does it effects on the security?

Comment: If `SELinux` is enable, you should check if it allow cgi script to execute and make sure ownership of php file, and allow it executable.

Comment: Thankyou, i am currently reeading documentation from here http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `SELinux` config is ok, it seems that this error occured because server configuration.

If you have installed `php`, then make sure that it is loaded by `apache` and `apache` is associated with `php` handler.

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And you should check your `.htaccess`. It may have some configurations that overrided apache's config.

Comment: Don't mind, i'm really new to linux, i run those commands but it shows error: bash: LoadModule: command not found
bash: LoadModule: command not found
 Thanks

Comment: @rakibtg: No, you should check that those lines is in your apache config and are not commented.

Comment: Ops! i think i have nothing like **LoadModule php...** in my httpd.conf file , any idea?

Comment: @rakibtg: Do you have any `php.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`?

Comment: I think no there isn't any file like php.conf ! http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv7v1.png
What i should do now?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Oh, You should install `mod_php`.

Comment: How i can install mod_php, because i have already installed apache?

Comment: Maybe `yum --enablerepo=centosplus install mod_php`

Comment: This worked for me after I restarted Apache. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 6):

```
yum install mod_php -y
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: Please note that on a `CentOS 6` machine, `systemctl restart httpd.service` will return a "command not found." `service httpd restart` would be the correct means of restarting the httpd service.

Comment: Thanks worked, can I specify the php version?